# How do I disable "Apple News Spotlight" in Mojave?

Tags: macos, notifications, mojave, news.app

This new "feature" showed up recently and won't stop pinging me with news I don't care about from an app I've never opened and can't uninstall: `/Applications/News.app`

How do I at least disable the morning notifications it pushes?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the notifications in `System Preferences -> Notifications`?

Comment: i actually did finally find that menu after seeing another question for the apple watch--fortunately all these devices share essentially the same ui conventions. i switched all those off and we'll see tomorrow morning if those kill the push notifications. if not i'll start working through the other answers one by one.

Answer (score 9):

Block notifications from the app in "System Preferences" -> "Notifications".  I'm not sure that it stops the app from from fetching news but it should block all notifications from it; including those that switch themselves back on for whatever reason.

[image]

Comment: Despite having done this several weeks back, every few days I still get the super-annoying news screen. The screenshot is out of date for Catalina. There is a master toggle at the top. That's what I had switched off.  I've just tried switching it on, just so I can uncheck everything and then switch it off again. Let's see if this stops the rot(ten Apple).

Comment: Nope, Five minutes later it is back again. For shame, Apple. For shame.

Answer (score 3):

In News.app, choose File → Manage Notifications, and uncheck notifications from each channel.

[image]

Comment: yep, i checked in that menu and "Apple News Spotlight" is the only channel turned on, and it was the one that was showing up every morning. i'm going to try re-enabling News's access to notifications and switching this off, and if it works tomorrow will mark this answer as accepted!

Comment: so it seems that the news app reactivates its channels after you toggle them off :/ so the answer here is really to take away notifications permissions at a higher level from the News app in the system notifications settings